# Android ViewPager replace current Fragment, but when sliding back the initial one doesn't gets reloaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

My problem is that I have a ViewPager which displays 4 Fragments (lets say: A, B, C, D). But sometimes when the user clicks on something I need to replace for example A with another Fragment (lets say E). I manged to do this by overriding getItemPosition and writing a custom setCurrentItem method in my ViewPager. Here are my classes:

**MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter**:

```
public class MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Map<Integer, Fragment> overrides;

    public void setOverride(int position, Fragment fragment) {
        overrides.put(position, fragment);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public final Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        Fragment fragment = overrides.remove(position);
        if (fragment != null) {
            return fragment;
        } else {
            ... // return corresponding base Fragment (A, B, C, D)
        }
    }

    @Override
    // this is overrideden to ensure 
    public final int getItemPosition(final Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

And my **MyViewPager**:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    ...

    public MyAdapter adapter() {
        return (MyAdapter) this.getAdapter();
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(final int item, final Fragment fragment) {
        if (this.getAdapter() == null) {
            return;
        }

        this.adapter().setOverride(item, fragment);

        if (item == this.getCurrentItem()) {
            this.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            this.setCurrentItem(item);
        }
    }

}
```

So this works flawlessly, but when I swipe back from the Fragment and swipe back I want to see A displaying again, but I still see E.

Has anyone got a solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Stick a break point on getItem and see if it hits it again. If you're swiping away from the first fragment and straight back to it, you'll only see getItem called for the third item where it's preloading the off screen content. See here for more details - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29

Comment: Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time on your `setCurrentItem`.

Comment: Overriding setCurrentItem and calling notifyDataSetChanged before super.setCurrentItem works, but it really makes things slow down. Maybe there is a way to invalidate only the Fragment which got overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, I managed to get it work without performance loss. Basically I call notifyDataSetChanged in the overridden setCurrentItem, but only if the current Fragment is not a base fragment. If anyone interested here are my classes:

The **MyPageAdapter:**

```
public abstract class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final Context context;

    private final Map<Integer, Fragment> fragmentOverrides;

    private final Map<Integer, Fragment> fragmentReferences;

    private final Map<Integer, Class<? extends Fragment>> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(final Context context, final FragmentManager fragmentManager, final Map<Integer, Class<? extends Fragment>> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
        this.fragmentOverrides = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();
        this.fragmentReferences = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();
        this.fragments = new HashMap<Integer, Class<? extends Fragment>>(fragments);
    }

    private Fragment getItemAt(final int position) {
        final Fragment overrideFragment = this.fragmentOverrides.remove(position);

        if (overrideFragment != null) {
            return overrideFragment;
        }

        return Fragment.instantiate(this.context, this.fragments.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public final Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        final Fragment fragment = this.getItemAt(position);
        this.fragmentReferences.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    public final Class<? extends Fragment> getInitialFragmentClass(final int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public final int getItemPosition(final Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public final Fragment getFragment(final int position) {
        return this.fragmentReferences.get(position);
    }

    public final boolean isInitialFragment(final Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
        return this.fragments.values().contains(fragmentClass);
    }

    public final void setOverride(final int position, final Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragmentOverrides.put(position, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public final void destroyItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position, final Object object) {
        this.fragmentReferences.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

And the **MyViewPager:**

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public MyViewPager(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public final MyPageAdapter adapter() {
        if (this.getAdapter() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!(this.getAdapter() instanceof MyPageAdapter)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid adapter! The adapter must extend MyPageAdapter!");
        }

        return ((MyPageAdapter) this.getAdapter());
    }

    public final Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
        if (this.getAdapter() == null || this.getCurrentItem() < 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.adapter().getFragment(this.getCurrentItem());
    }

    public final void reselectCurrentItem() {
        if (this.getAdapter() != null) {
            this.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void forceRefreshIfNeeded() {
        if (this.getAdapter() != null && 0 <= this.getCurrentItem() && this.getCurrentItem() < this.getAdapter().getCount()) {
            final Fragment currentFragment = this.adapter().getFragment(this.getCurrentItem());

            if (currentFragment != null && !currentFragment.getClass().equals(this.adapter().getInitialFragmentClass(this.getCurrentItem()))) {
                this.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(final int item) {
        this.forceRefreshIfNeeded();
        super.setCurrentItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(final int item, final boolean smoothScroll) {
        this.forceRefreshIfNeeded();
        super.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(final int item, final Fragment fragment) {
        if (this.getAdapter() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!this.adapter().isInitialFragment(fragment.getClass())) {
            this.adapter().setOverride(item, fragment);
        }

        if (item == this.getCurrentItem()) {
            this.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            this.setCurrentItem(item);
        }
    }

}
```